# Decomposition of a matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

Let $M$ be a real matrix of size $m$ x $n$.
Show that it is possible to find a vector $a$ of size $n$ and a vector $b$ of size $m$ such that

$M a=\sigma b$,

$\|a\|_{2}=1$,

$\|b\|_{2}=1$ and

$\sigma=\|M\|_{2}$.

I have tried using the definition of the matrix norm induced by vectors in vain. Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

By definition (or by a trivial theorem from any equivalent definition),
$$
\|M\|_2=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Mx\|_2\ ,
$$
the set $\ S^{n-1}=\big\{x\,\big|\,\|x\|_2=1\big\}\subset\mathbb{R}^n\ $ is compact, and the function $\ x\mapsto\|M\|_2\ $ is continuous, so it attains its supremum on $\ S^{n-1}\ $.

Comment: I've tried fooling around a bit your hint. I can't see how the function reaching its supremum on the set will help me prove the equality. Can you give another hint?

Comment: If $\ a\ $ is the element of $\ S^{n-1}\ $ which attains the supremum, then $\ \|a\|_2=1\ $, because $\ a\in S^{n-1}\ $, and $\ \|Ma\|_2=$$\|M\|_2=$$\sigma\ $, because $\ \|Mx\|_2\ $ attains its supremum at $\ x=a\ $.  If $\ \sigma\ne0\ $, what is $\ \|\sigma^{-1}Ma\|_2\ $?